# How do I get index of selected slice in Pie Chart View with ios-charts?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I can't figure out how to make a UILabel visible if a slice is selected in a Pie Chart View. I need to know how to identify if a slice was selected and then what slice was selected so I can put the right text in a UILabel and then unhide the label.

pseudocode:

```
if sliceSelected == true {

    var index = sliceSelected.index

    label.text = categoryArray[index]

    label.hidden = false

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me. Attach an `enum` value as the `data` field of each entry, then analyze that value within the `chartValueSelected` delegate method.

For instance, if you have two slices, create the enum

```
internal enum SliceType {
    case pepperoni
    case cheese
}
```

Then when constructing the `PieChartDataSet`, construct your `PieChartDataEntry` objects with their `SliceType` as associated data:

```
let entry = PieChartDataEntry(value: pepperoniValue,
                              data: SliceType.pepperoni as AnyObject?)
```

Now make sure to set your view controller as the pie chart's delegate. Then in your `chartValueSelected` delegate method, do something like the following:

```
func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
    // Extract the SliceType from the selected value
    guard let sliceType = entry.data as? SliceType else {
        return
    }

    switch sliceType {
    case .pepperoni:
        // Configure the view for pepperoni being selected
    case .cheese:
        // Configure the view for cheese being selected
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you do it. Add `ChartViewDelegate` to your class and then insert the method below into the body of your code. Any thing that you want to happen if someone touches a value on your chart should go in the body of this function.

```
func chartValueSelected(chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, highlight: ChartHighlight) {

}
```

Shout out to this very useful tutorial for the ios-charts API: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

Each data separated by X axis of highlight. I can do it by doing this.

```
public func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
        pieChartView.highlightValues(nil)
        print(highlight.x)
        if highlight.x == 0.0 {

        } else if highlight.x == 1.0 {

        } else {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried storing the selected slice in a variable like:

`var slice: NSMutableDictionary = [:]`

And then set the value for forKeyPath: index?